# Javascript - I thought this would change

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to get to grips with passing by reference vs. value, and from what I understand, JS objects are passed by reference.

If that is the case, why does the second console.log statement not produce a capitalised version of the object property?

Any clarification would be great!!!

```js
var string = {
  text: 'This is a string inside an object',
};


console.log(string.text);

string.text.toUpperCase();

console.log(string.text);
```

Comment: [*"The toUpperCase() method returns the value of the string converted to upper case. toUpperCase() **does not affect the value of the string itself**."*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) Directly from documentation on MDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **[`String#toUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)** method  wouldn't update the original string it just returns the capitalized string. So you need to update the property value by the returned value.

```js
var string = {
  text: 'This is a string inside an object',
};


console.log(string.text);

string.text = string.text.toUpperCase();

console.log(string.text);
```

Comment: Thanks! On a side note, when I re-assign an object inside a function, it doesn't change the original - do you know why?

Comment: @Joshua if it works like c# at all, your changing what the variable refers to in the method, NOT the reference of the original object.

Answer (score 0):

`.toUpperCase()` does not change the original string, but returns a new string.

Try this instead:

```js
var string = {
  text: 'This is a string inside an object',
};


console.log(string.text);

string.text = string.text.toUpperCase();

console.log(string.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.toUpperCase();` returns an uppercase string but it does not modify the original argument

Answer (score 0):

From MDN link below: JavaScript strings are immutable. This means that once a string is created, it is not possible to modify it. However, it is still possible to create another string based on an operation on the original string. For example:toUpperCase()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

From MDN link below: The toUpperCase() method returns the value of the string converted to upper case. toUpperCase() does not affect the value of the string itself.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase